# Error : Android BOX integration

Tags: android, json, api, integration, box

I am developing an android app with box api integration. In which I have to fetch videos from logged in users' uploaded videos. I also need to show video thumbnails. I found something from below link.

**Link:=> https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-a-thumbnail-for-a-file**

But in response I got the contents of image. i don't know how to fetch that type of response.
Can anyone help me please to come out of this???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Get Thumbnail API can generate either a png or jpg thumbnail file from a video. But it cannot generate a video thumbnail (such as a mp4 or gif file) from a video.